# Porque no se realizan los cambios en mis vistas?

Tags: html, laravel, scss

Estoy teniendo un problema al momento de realizar cambios en mis vistas ya que cuando modifico el código en el .scss mis cambios no se visualizan en la vista, pero si modifico la vista desde el navegador al inspeccionar un elemento me los toma. Ahora no entiendo porque cuando realmente modifico mi codigo no sucede nada.

Este seria el bloque de código de mi hoja de estilos: _main-sidebar.scss

```
    // Tree view menu
  .nav-treeview {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left:30px;
```

No se porque el margin-left no me lo modifica.

Y esta sería la parte de mi vista que estoy modificando: sidebar.blade.php

```
<li class="nav-item has-treeview mt-4">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket ml-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <p class="ml-2">
                    Productos
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ route('products.view') }}" class="nav-link text-white">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                        <p>Productos</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ route('brands.view') }}" class="nav-link text-white">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                        <p>Marcas</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ route('models.view') }}" class="nav-link text-white">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                        <p>Modelos</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ route('ptype.view') }}" class="nav-link text-white">
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                        <p>Tipo de Producto</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
               
                
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Trate darle estilos desde el html pero tampoco funciona. Nose si tiene que ver algo con Laravel o simplemente estoy incluyendo algo mal.

Este es mi head.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('backend/build/_main-sidebar.scss')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/dist/css/adminlte.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/dist/css/adminlte.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css') }}">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/toastr.min.css') }}">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('backend/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('backend/plugins/select2-bootstrap4-theme/select2-bootstrap4.min.css') }}">
```

El cuarto link que estoy incluyendo que es el siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('backend/build/scss/_main-sidebar.scss')}}">
```

Es donde tengo los estilos del sidebar que estoy tratando de modificar. Que se encuentra en public > backend > build > scss > varios archivos .scss

Comment: Bueno una posibilidad de que no suceda nada es que deberías quitar la cache del navegador cuando estas en desarrollo, la cache muchas veces no muestra los cambios en el navegador.

Comment: Hola, no deberías de enviar los estilos con extensión .scss al navegador porque estos en su mayoría no los entienden, tienes que poner los estilos ya compilados a .css, tal vez sea este tu problema

Comment: A que te refieres con que esten compilados a .css, tienes algun ejemplo o guía? @ossoboy